# How to keep a pointer to each word in an array of character pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

Title pretty much explains it all. I'm just curious as to how you would go about doing it. I've looked it up online and what I found doesn't necessarily give me definite answers in the sense of that they don't seem to be what I'm actually looking for. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: `strtok`, can automate parsing a cstring, make sure the array stays in scope and unchanged. Otherwise, allocate/copy for each pointer returned. If you already have the sentence (words) in a buffer, then just iterate over the buffer assigning the address for the beginning of each word to your array of pointers. There are a minimum 400 examples already on the site. Search `strtok`.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  Post your code.

Comment: @SidS That's the issue I don't know where to start. I need to type a bunch of words in several lines (which I'm assuming means that you input "hello world", press enter, input another char, press enter, repeat). However, I also need to do it how the title says without using any arrays (i.e. char ** arr = new char[SIZE];). Some of the things I've seen get me so far or aren't exactly what I'm looking for. I really just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach. Make sure `char *str` is allocated on the heap so the pointers in the vector are not dangling.

```
std::vector<char*> word_pointers(char *str)
{
    std::vector<char*> words;        // to store pointers to beginning of words

    bool start = true;               // marks start of word

    for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i)     // expects null-terminated string
    {
        if (start && str[i] != ' ')
            words.push_back(str + i);

        start = (str[i] == ' ');     // is the next character qualified for word
     }

     return words;
}
```

Mind that the `char *` elements of the vector are terminated only at the end of `str`. An alternative could be to replace spaces with `\0`, but then it would be hard to read the whole string.